# Service module costume response after creating node

Tags: services

I want to get costume return from services module after creating a node.
I would like to checks if the there is a similar title, and if so, to return the number of times it exists.
(Services 3 / Drupal 7)
What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have following hook to do the response modifications,

```
function hook_services_request_postprocess_alter($controller, $args, &$result) {

}
```